# while he works or while he working or while he is working

Tags: grammar

I want to tell my friend "please take photos while the painter does something" but I don't know which one is correct way to say it.

"Please take photos while the painter paints"
"Please take photos while the painter painting"
"Please take photos while the painter is painting"

If these sentences are related to grammar rules please let me know too.

Answer (score 2):

A native speaker might say something like 'It would be good if you could take photos while the painter is actually painting'.